# Controller with dependency injection does not work

Tags: php, symfony

When I inject the Request class of Simfony it works well for me, but I just created a class called FormRequest that "extends" from Request, I thought this would work, since it is still a Request instance, but it is not, I get an error.

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Http\Controllers\BlogController::validateAction() must be an instance of AppBundle\Http\FormRequest, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request given, called in /var/www/html/api-erp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php on line 151
Exception
```

My class FormRequest.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Http;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\{JsonResponse, Request, Response};

class FormRequest extends Request 
{

}
```

Controller BlogController.php is:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Http\Controllers;

use AppBundle\Http\FormRequest;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\{Request, JsonResponse};
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog", name="blog_index")
    */
    public function validateAction(FormRequest $request)
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['success' => true]);
    }
}
```

> Simfony versión: 3.4.*

Comment: Check this out: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/http_foundation.html#overriding-the-request

Comment: Did you try clear your cache? Also, check services.yml to make sure you are not manually setting up the dependency injection

Comment: Its still a Request, but a Request is not your FormRequest. You get a Request, but you want to have a FormRequest. To achieve this you have to override the Request as described in the link of the first comment

Comment: The solution to the first comment works, but now I would only accept the "FormRequest" classes. My intention is to have many "extended" classes of FormRequest. For example: `class UpdateBlogRequest extends FormRequest { }`. That is my intention finally. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You missing something.

Symfony use the ParamConverter feature to inject the request in your action. If you want to override it you also have to create a custom converter and use the correct priority in the service to avoid the error.

More explanation [in symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter)

Comment: No, Symfony does not use the ParamConverter for the Request object.  Being able to inject the request goes all the way back to S2.0.  Long before the param converter was even thought of.  Plus the request object is not an entity.  The request object actually has it's very own bit of code inside of the HttpKernel::handle(Raw$request) code.  It ultimately uses a RequestValueResolver.  It can be worth while to step through the request handling process.  Lots of good stuff in there.

Comment: Thanks for your correction and clarification. Should I delete my answer as it is irrelevant ?